# Save data to pinia store outside component

Tags: vue.js, pinia

I'm trying to create a VueJS app, with typescript and pinia
I would like to store data from an api with pinia

So I have this code

main.ts

```
import { createApp, App as Application } from 'vue';
import { createPinia } from 'pinia';
import App from './App.vue';

const pinia = createPinia();

const app = createApp(App);
app.use(pinia);
app.mount('#app');
```

store.ts

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';


interface State {
    data: Data[]
}

const useStore = defineStore('app', {
    state: (): State => ({
        data: []
    }),
    getters: {

    },
    actions: {
    },
});

export default useStore;
```

App.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        Hello world
    </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import Axios from 'axios';
import useStore from './store';
import {onMounted} from "vue";

onMounted(() => {
  const store = useStore();
  Axios.get('/myapi').then((data) => {
    store.data = data.data;
  });
})
</script>
```

so this code works

But I would like to fetch data outside the component, I want to have a file api.ts with all axios call so I tried this

api.ts

```
import Axios from 'axios';
import useStore from './store';

const store = useStore();

const api = {
    getData() {
        return Axios.get('/myapi').then((data) => {
            store.data = data.data;
        });
    },
};

export default api;
```

and then in App.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        Hello world
    </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import Axios from 'axios';
import useStore from './store';
import {onMounted} from "vue";
import api from "./api";

onMounted(() => {
  api.getData()
})

</script>
```

then I have an error : nia.cjs:1696 Uncaught Error: []: "getActivePinia()" was called but there was no active Pinia. Did you forget to install pinia?

I can't understand how to fetch data in specific file and save data to pinia
Could you help me please ?

Comment: useStore exists as a function to prevent a srore from being accessed too early. Call it where you use it, not at the top of a module. Normally you just wouldn't have this problem. `return Axios.get('/myapi')` - this logic belongs to a store, this is what actions are for.

Comment: It’s described in the documentation https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/outside-component-usage.html

Comment: Have you tried using `usePinia()` ? 
`const pinia = usePinia();` and then `const store = useStore(pinia);`